# C# replace only one thing in file

Tags: c#

I made a program that modifies a local html page and replaces a certain value in it as you can see here:

```
string j = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Replace " + listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text + "/" + intlstv2.ToString() + " With?");

var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
foreach(HtmlElement lnk in links)
{
    if (lnk.GetAttribute("className") == "point" && lnk.InnerText == listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text || lnk.GetAttribute("className") == "point tekort" && lnk.InnerText == listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lnk.InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show("Replacing with: " + j.ToString());

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Fin.html", this.webBrowser1.DocumentText);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Fin.html", System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Fin.html").Replace(lnk.InnerText, j));
    }
}
```

And in the html file:

```
<td class="point">14,5</td> <---- Value that I want replaced
<td class="average" title="Med">14,5</td> <---- Value that I want to keep
```

The value selected in listview 2 = 14,5 but the problem I'm having is that in the html, 14,5 exists twice (once for the class name point and the second for the class name med) I would only like to replace the innertext of classname point without changing the med's innertext.

How would I do this?

Comment: You could add an extra attribute like in "<td class="point" my="spot">14,5</td>" to locate your unique cell for replacement.

Answer (score 4):

You could find better success by traversing the HTML document as an object tree rather than a "blob" of string.

That being said, using `HtmlDocument` to do this will be painful as it doesn't offer a way to introspect easily by class name, attribute values, etc. That being said, you could call `GetElementByTagName` and fetch all the `td` elements, and filter these by the `class` attribute. A bit of complexity, but I guess manageable.

I usually use the `HtmlAgilityPack` library, which provides many, many more methods and objects which will allow you to find your html elements with greater ease.  Strongly recommend you use it!